# Populating MicroCharts From API Get response \ Observable Collection

Tags: c#, observablecollection, skiasharp

I have a working API that returns a collection of 'Shifts' (consider these in the context of a timesheet)
The data is returned successfully from the API as highlighted in the extract below.:

```
[{"id":1006,"wI_Date":"2020-05-01T00:00:00","wI_Start_Time":"2020-05-01T08:00:00","wI_End_Time":"2020-05-01T17:00:00","name":"Surgery 1","rate":60.0000,"paid":"N         ","revenue":"540       "},{"id":1007,"wI_Date":"2020-05-04T00:00:00","wI_Start_Time":"2020-05-04T08:00:00","wI_End_Time":"2020-05-04T17:00:00","name":"Medical Surgery 2","rate":45.0000,"paid":"N         ","revenue":"405       "},{"id":1008,"wI_Date":"2020-05-07T00:00:00","wI_Start_Time":"2020-05-07T08:00:00","wI_End_Time":"2020-05-07T17:00:00","name":"TEST Medical Surgery","rate":45.0000,"paid":"N         ","revenue":"405"}]
```

I have 100s of records in the return that span over the full calendar year (By "wI_Date") and indeed as time goes by and the data set grows will also span over multiple years

Im trying to work out how to group the records by Month\Year so I can add them to a list of Entries for a Micorcharts.BarGraph - without grouping at the backend.
It want to then Sum up the "Revenue" values for that month and its that value i want to pass to my chart as the Entry

A shift is defined as:

```
public class Shift
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime WiDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime WiStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime WiEndTime { get; set; }
        public int Practice { get; set; }
        public string Rate { get; set; }
        public string Paid { get; set; }
        public string Revenue { get; set; }
    }
```

My Call to the API looks like this:

```
var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(URL);
var shifts= = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shift>>(content);

OShifts = new  ObservableCollection<Shift>(shifts);
```

So I have a success ObservableCollection.. Im struggling with grouping that by year\date to add to the Entries for a Micorcharts.BarGraph..

to help below is a harded example of how to populate the chart..

```
private List<Entry> _entries = new List<Entry>
        {
            new Entry(200)
            {
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#3333FF"),
                Label = "TEST LABEL 1",
                ValueLabel = "200",


            },

            new Entry(400)
            {
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#FF141F"),
                Label = "TEST LABEL 2",
                ValueLabel = "400",


            },

            new Entry(300)
            {
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#49FF33"),
                Label = "TEST LABEL 3",
                ValueLabel = "300",


            },

MyBarChart.Chart = new BarChart { Entries = _entries };
```

Anyone have an ideas or example code..??

Thanks For reading..

Comment: your problem is not so abvious, which year/date exactly you need to group by ?

Comment: Sorry..

So i need all the data entries in the Observable Collection grouped per date and year...(as per WIDate field in observable collection)

So for example

2020 - Jan - (sum of revenue = ) £1000
2020 - Feb- (sum of revenue = ) £1200
2020 - March- (sum of revenue = ) £1300

etc etc

Comment: please see my answer and let me know if you have any other question

Answer (score 0):

you can do so

```
var groupedShifts = 
    OShifts.GroupBy(sh => new { sh.WiDate.Year, sh.WiDate.Month },(key,group)=>new {
            Period=`${key.Year}-${key.Month}`
            SumRevenue = group.Sum(sh=>Decimal.Parse(sh.Revenue))
   }).ToList();
```

I assume that your Shift.Revenue is a safe decimal value and can not be something else.
Here I return a list of Objects that have each one Period and SumRevenue but you can customize the return as you want.

Comment: Thanks.. sorry I may have mis interpreted your solution but im not sure how to extract data from this..

The solution appears to supply 1 object and I dont understand how to extract the SumRevenue per month..

Sorry im very new to dev and so am a complete novice and accept it will most likely be down to my lack of experience..

Comment: Not a problem, we all came from there :),
in fact, when you use GroupBy and you mention 
```
new { sh.WiDate.Year, sh.WiDate.Month }
```
you are grouping by year and month, like you want.
in you example, you will have one group for the year=2020,Month=05

Comment: Sorry Im probably driving you mad at this stage but im still confused..

Are you suggesting that I need to run the code you kindly provided for each Year,Month I wish to extract the Sum.Revenue value for..
Eg - to get the Sum.Revenue for '2020' , '04' I need to change the query to:?

var groupedShifts =
                OShifts.GroupBy(sh => new { sh.WiDate.Year, sh.WiDate.Month }, (key, group) => new {
                    Year = "2020",
                    Month = "04",
                    SumRevenue = group.Sum(sh => Decimal.Parse(sh.Revenue))
                }).ToList();

Comment: If I reword it slightly that may help..

Essentially is there a way of extracting the Year, Month and Sum Revenue for each so I would have a Sum revenue value for:
2020 - 01
2020 - 02
2020 - 03 etc


- perhaps a CSV sting may be an easier way?

Essentially the output im looking for is a Sum Revenue Figure for each month of each year..
Ill then use those values to populate the datapoints for my graph.

Comment: Please see the update I have made, you now have a sumrevenue for each period